# Submitting PHP form with children value from iOS

Tags: php, ios, arrays, forms, children

So I'm trying to submit a form from my application, and I'm facing a problem when the server expects me to send children values.

Up to now, I've been able to send simple values as follow:

```
$values['email'] = email; //server side
```

I created my request like follow:

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://test.com"]];
post = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"email=test@mail.com"];        // <= that's where I fill my form in

NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];

NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [postData length]];

[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setHTTPBody:postData];

NSURLConnection *urlConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
```

Now, my problem is here: the server is expecting me to fill this in:

```
$values['plainPassword']['first'] = password;
```

So I tried to replace my post with

```
post = [NSString stringWithFormat=@"plainPassword['first']=pass"];
```

But this doesn't work. Does anyone know how I should fill this child var?
I haven't found anything about it on stackOverflow as everything I found was how to fill simple vars.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I just figured out what was wrong, the server doesn't expect me to put the quotes.

Basically, the solution is as follows:

Server side:
    $values['plainPassword']['first'] = password;

App side:
    post = [NSString stringWithFormat=@"plainPassword[first]=pass"];